# VBA: my program is throwing compile error ByRef

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors, byref

I'm working with a program that was running. I made a copy from which to test making my code more modular. Below is what used to be one sub run inside a loop changed to two subs run by a call to the first.

```
Sub Trendline()
Dim eqn, name As String
Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim i As Integer
For Each cht in Worksheets(1).ChartObjects
    If cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines.Count > 0 Then
        cht.Activate
        name = Split(ActiveChart.name)(1)
        i = Worksheets(name).Range("Z2").Value 'indicates what kind of trendline
        eqn = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Text
        'the trendline has both R-square and Equation displayed
        eqn = Split(eqn, Chr(10))(0)
        Worksheets(name).Range("AA1").Value = MakeEqn(i, eqn)
    End If
Next cht
End Sub

Function MakeEqn(i As Integer, eqn As String) As String
'1 is linear, 2 polynomial, 3 polynomial order 3
'4 is power, 5 exponential, 6 logarithmic
    eqn = Replace(eqn, "y = ", "")
If i = 6 Then ' removes 6 from options
    eqn = Replace(eqn, "ln", "*LN")
    'Break
Else
    eqn = Replace(eqn, "x", "*x")
    If i = 1 Then ' removes 1 from options
        'Break
    ElseIf i = 5 Then ' removes 5 from options
        eqn = Replace(eqn, "e", "*EXP(")
        eqn = eqn & ")" ' add ")" to end of string
        ' Break
    ElseIf i = 4 Then ' removes 4 from options
        eqn = Replace(eqn, "x", "x^")
        'Break
    Else ' for both 2 and 3
        eqn = Replace(eqn, "x2", "x^2") ' 2 is now done
        If i = 3 Then
            eqn = Replace(eqn, "x3", "x^3")
        End If
    End If
End If
MakeEqn = eqn
End Function
```

Here, the "eqn" in the call to MakeEqn is highlighted and it throws the following Compile Error.
[image: Compile Error: ByRef]

I'm frustrated because I'm passing a string into a function that calls for a string, but the compiler claims there is a type mismatch. What should I be doing here?

Comment: You have declared `eqn` in `TrendLine` to be a `Variant`.  Declare it to be a `String` instead (i.e. `Dim eqn As String, name As String`).  You can't pass a `Variant` into a function `ByRef` if the `Function` is expecting to receive a `String`.

Comment: P.S.  Once again, your screenshot didn't match your posted code.  (But at least this time the posted code included enough relevant info to be able to reproduce and identify the error :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `TrendLine` subroutine, you have declared `eqn` to be a `Variant`:

```
Dim eqn, name As String
```

In your `MakeEqn` function, you are expecting to receive (by reference) a `String`:

```
Function MakeEqn(i As Integer, eqn As String) As String
```

You cannot pass a `Variant` to a `ByRef` `String`.  (It will generate a "ByRef argument type mismatch" error.)

---

The easiest fix is to declare `eqn` to be a `String` in `TrendLine`, i.e.

```
Dim eqn As String, name As String
```

Alternatively, you could pass the variable `ByVal`, which would force a conversion from `Variant` to `String`:

```
Function MakeEqn(i As Integer, ByVal eqn As String) As String
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is a problem because variable **`eqn`** is implicitly declared as a Variant type on the second line of your example: `Dim eqn, name As String`. In VBA, you need to explicitly declare **every** variable even when in the same line (unless it is a Variant indeed), like this:

```
Dim eqn As String, name As String
```

Comment: oh wow, that was totally misrepresented to me. I had no idea.

Comment: @LKadue Different types of Visual Basic have different rules - in VB.Net (if I remember correctly) `Dim eqn, name As String` **would** declare both variables to be of type `String`.  So you need to be careful that what you read / are taught is relevant to the particular "flavour" of VB that you are using.

Comment: @YowE3K: nicely noted, thanks. However, this q is tagged **Excel VBA** :-)

Comment: Gene, that was a comment to the OP, who had said what I took to mean that he/she had been taught something different.  So I was just pointing out that they may have been taught something relevant to VB.Net, and they shouldn't necessarily assume that VBA will behave the same.  (Your answer is perfectly fine - I have no issue with it.)

Comment: @YowE3K:  I think you are right on the money with this: "...and they shouldn't necessarily assume that VBA will behave the same" because the inevitably do. Thanks again, a great comment.